# Drill Down Search using Sql

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

it seems like alot of ecommerce sites these days are providing products filters to search for items. For example you can search items by WIDTH,HEIGHT,TV SIZE, Furniture Type etc.

now if it was a simple website with just a few searchable filters then its easy to do, but I am managing a website which sells furniture,appliance & electronics and every category has alot of sub categories as well. for example:

Appliance:
         Laundry
                Searchable Attributes (Washer,Dryer,Washer Type..Microwave,Width, Height)
 Electronics
         Tv(Tv Size, Width)
         Games (ps3, Genre,Sale Date)

I am sure you get the idea. an ecomerece sites offers basic categoies and then every category could have sub categories OR Searable filters to drill down your search.

what would be the best way to do this using MS SQL Server & Asp.net. I am interested in creating a optimized searchable schema in SQL.

any Hints, Suggestions will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

The simple concept is that instead of having a column for each of your model's attributes (such a genre, sale date, etc for a ps3 game), youll have another table, named Attributes, where the attributes and their types will be listed, and a third table, where your main model instances (ps3 game) will be linked with attributes via 3 columns:

- Model Id (the id of the ps3 game)
- Attribute Id
- Attribute Value

This concept might be harder to manage, and require more complicated queries, but it will alow addition of new products / categorites in the easiest way.

Of course, with this model, if few products share a common attribute (sugh as pc game and ps3 game sharing a genre), you'll have the attribute defined only once, and both model will be linked to it, allowing a common search query on different products.

Answer (score 0):

Too much for a single question.  Look for a book on database design.  For a drill down you can have a table with as many PK columns as drill downs.    But when it comes to details you will need separate tables as TV does not have the same details as a stereo.

Comment: Blam, how is this too much for a question? all I was asking was a good technique to build a drill down searches. I have done this on  many sites, but i am hunting for best ideas, maybe you can suggest me a book which talks about drill down searches?